# Filling two nested drop dwon list when editing an entry in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have two nested drop down list. 
one drop down show group,the other show sub group.
i have coded data source of subgroup drop down list on group drop down list selected indexed change event.
What I'm trying to do is set a drop down list to be whatever its value is in the database when editing an entry.
i have used data row.
i have two tables.documentgroup(GroupId,parentId,groupTitle,subGroupTitle) and documents(DocID,GroupID,Title,url)
in my drop down lists i have added list item like this

```
<asp:ListItem Text = "--select group--" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>
```

when i click on editing a document,i have this.

```
    protected void grdDocuments_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "DoEdit")
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            int DocID = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            ViewState["DocumentID"] = DocID;
            ViewState["EditMode"] = "Edit";
            DataTable dtDocuments = DataLayer.Documents.SelectRow(DocID).Tables["Documents"];
            if (dtDocuments.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                DataRow drDocuments = dtDocuments.Rows[0];

                txtDocTitle.Text = drDocuments["DocTitle"].ToString();
                txtDocPubYear.Text = drDocuments["DocPubYear"].ToString();

                    ddlDocGroupTitle.SelectedValue = drDocuments["ParentID"].ToString();


                    ddlDocSubGroupTitle.SelectedValue = drDocuments["DocGroupID"].ToString();

                ViewState["DocCurrentUrl"] = drDocuments["DocUrl"].ToString();
                mvDocuments.SetActiveView(vwEdit);
            }
        }
```

but i get this error

> 'ddlDocSubGroupTitle' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it
>   does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

and this is the same for ddldocgroupTitle.
i have made an inner join between two tables.

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I could not really grasp your question, but it looks like you want to have 2 dropdown, and upon selection in the first, the second gets populated/filtered correct?!?

I recommend that you use javascript/Jquery to do so. Upon page load, issue a [ajax get request](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fill the "main" dropdown, and [upon selection](https://api.jquery.com/change/) on the first one, you issue a second ajax request to fetch the possible values of the second one...

A alternative is to fetch the items for the first dropdown AND all the values possible for the second, storing the result in some hidden-field [data](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/). Then upon selection of the first value, you can only filter + display relevant data.

Comment: no,i have already done it,but when i want to edit an entry,drop down list dont fill from databse.they give me error,that i had written.